# 2 Scanners but one onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on a mobile application in Android Studio and have 2 buttons.
Each button will initiate a barcode/QR scan using the Zxing library.

The problem that I am having is that I am assigning the results from the first scan to the button text and that is working fine.

However, when it comes to assigning the results from the second scan to its button then it does not work as there is only one onActivityResult?

I am aware that the system will just ignore it if I copy and paste the code and try to Override an onActivityResult2 as it is not recognised by the system.

However, how am I meant to get around this problem?

Here is my code for the onActivityResult and also onActivityResult2 just to show what I am trying to achieve:

onActivityResult:

WORKING CODE:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (result != null) {
        //if qrcode has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            try {
                //converting the data to json
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (buttonId == R.id.buttonScan) {
                    machineType = result.getContents();
                    scanBarcode.setText("Machine Type: " + machineType);
                } else if (buttonId == R.id.buttonScan2) {
                    workOrderNumber = result.getContents();
                    scanWorkOrder.setText("Work Order Number: " + workOrderNumber);
                }
                else if (buttonId == 0) {
                    ???
                }

            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Buttons to invoke library:

```
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;
private IntentIntegrator qrScan2;

int buttonId = 0; //THIS IS GLOBAL

 //Initialise Buttons
    scanBarcode = findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
    scanWorkOrder = findViewById(R.id.buttonScan2);
    submit = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Initialize Scanners
    qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);


    scanBarcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qrScan.initiateScan();
            buttonId = R.id.buttonScan;
        }
    });

    scanWorkOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qrScan.initiateScan();
            buttonId = R.id.buttonScan2;

        }
    });
```

Comment: We cannot see the type of qrScan and qrScan2.

Comment: @greenapps updated. apologies again

Comment: `onActivityResult(int requestCode...` Which values do you get for requestCode? Are they different?

Comment: Please tell what happens when you click a scan button. Is your activity covered by a scanner window/activity? Can you invoke two scanners at the same time?

Comment: @greenapps yeah when I click each button it goes to the camera as a scanner.. suppose I could I'm just interested in getting the different results?? I'm not too sure about the requestcode it wont let me debug

Comment: You can log the requestCode. Or Toast it.

Comment: So you cannot start two scanners at the same time!? Why dont you confirm or deny? This can take ages else.

Comment: `int buttonId = 0;`. Add as global variable.

Comment: `buttonId = R.id.buttonScan;`. Add to onClick of first button.

Comment: `buttonId = R.id.buttonScan2;`. Add to onClick of second button.

Comment: In onActivity result toast(buttonId). Which value do you get? 0?

Comment: I can use the one scanner for both buttons @greenapps... the toast message is returning "false"?

Comment: Its an integer. So you will get a number. It can never display false. Please show your toast.

Comment: I was wondering the whole time why you used two scanner instances. You can do it with one i think. Just remove qrScan2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161098/discussion-between-rajeey3-and-greenapps).

Comment: okay @greenapps I have updated my code

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, "requestCode: " + requestCode + "\nbuttonId: " + buttonId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Put this as first line in onActivityResult. Tell the values for both buttons.

Comment: 1st button: requestcode=49374, buttonid = 2131230756 @greenapps

Comment: 2nd button: requestcode = 49374, buttonid = 2131230757 @greenapps

Comment: Well very nice. Your problem is solved then. Please adapt your code and show us what you did.

Comment: So then how do I code the if statement to determine the different results?? @greenapps

Comment: Well think about it! Compare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int buttonId = 0;
```

Add as global variable.

```
buttonId = R.id.buttonScan;
```

Add to onClick of first button.

```
buttonId = R.id.buttonScan2;
```

Add to onClick of second button.

Check what you get in onActivityResult and handle accordingly.

Comment: Please show your if statements as i fear you do it not optimally.

Comment: Thanks! @greenapps appreciate the help!

Comment: See above @greenapps

Comment: `if (buttonId == 2131230756)`. No good. It will work yes. But it is unreadable code and if you add another button above this one or in between your buttons the values will change and your code would not work any more. Change to `if (buttonId == R.id.buttonScan)`.

Comment: Also add an else statement for buttonId==0 or just other buttonIds. As it might work different on different devices. Then display a toast or whatever.

Comment: like so above @greenapps? what would I want to display in the toast?

Comment: In the toast you would display `"I have to add yet other code to handle the lifecycle of my activity"`.

Comment: okay great thanks for all the help @greenapps! greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two exact same methods while following `overloading` rules so

For two requests , you can have two different `requestCode` and later use `if` statement to identify your request type or button click response

```
startActivityForResult (intent, 100); // 100 for button 1
startActivityForResult (intent, 101); // 101 for button 2
```

in `ActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        //if qrcode has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            try {
                //converting the data to json
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                workOrderNumber = result.getContents();
                if(requestCode == 100)
                    scanBarcode.setText("Machine Type: " + machineType);
                else if(requestCode == 101)
                    scanWorkOrder.setText("Work Order Number: " + workOrderNumber);                 
             }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: would you have any code to show me so that I could go from there?

Comment: @Rajeey3 try the updated code , you just need to pass different `int values` as requestcode which starting the intent on different button clicks

Comment: where do I put the StartActivityforResult codes? oncreate? and also how does these codes know which buttons they are for? thanks though that makes sense! @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: @Rajeey3 that was a copy-paste typo, just use the overriden `onActivityResult` and remove the second one

Comment: `where do I put the StartActivityforResult codes? `. So you are not using startActivityForResult()? Ok. Then show your buttons onclick codes where you invoke the library. Please put all in your post. You should have started with it.